# Can the google spreadsheet api be used for print range definition

Tags: google-sheets-api

Please would someone give me the syntax for sending a range to a printer?

I have a script that defines what I want to print but I cannot find how to direct the print request to a driver and specify portrait/landscape etc.

Comment: Can you provide your current script? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Short answer is no because I do not have one. Even the macro recorder does not record anything other than the range to print. I want to include other details such as print.selected range as portrait